# Why doesn't this vb.6 ln(x) code work for numbers larger than 2?

Tags: vb6

I made this code for ln as a homework but it doesn't work for numbers larger than 2 !

```
If Val(txt.Text) <= 0 Then
  MsgBox "can't find ln !", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "ERROR": Exit Sub
Else
  sign = -1 
  Sum = x - 1
  r = 2

  For j = 2 To 3 Step 0
    t = sign * ((x - 1) ^ r / r)

    If Abs(t) >= 0.0000001 And Abs(t) <= 100000000# Then
      Sum = Sum + t
      sign = -sign
      r = r + 1
    Else
      GoTo 12
    End If
  Next
End If
```

Here's an image of the equation:

[image: Equation]

Comment: 1. we need more of your code. 2. your loop only goes from 2 to 3. GOTO...really?!?!

Comment: The loop also uses "Step 0" which means it won't increment

Comment: The code is wrong for the equation as well... you have more problems than you think...

Comment: I made it on porpuse,  because I want it to goes forever unless the condition is happen,  and I use r for increment and do the rest,  I found this way on the net and it works for infinite loops perfectly

Comment: and it works so well for numbers between 0 and 2 !

Comment: This isn't a vb6 problem, but a math/algorithm problem.  The reason it is working only between 0 and 2 is that the series expansion you're using is applicable only for x between 0 and 2 (specifically `0 < x <= 2`).  You need to use a different series expansion for other values/ranges.  See [Log Expansions](http://www.math.com/tables/expansion/log).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your help, specially MarkL, I did it! and I am so glad for this :)

here is the  final code if you are interested ^_^ :

```
        If Val(txt.Text) <= 0 Then
        MsgBox "can't find ln !", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "ERROR"
         Exit Sub

        ElseIf x < 0.51 Then
        sign = -1
        Sum = x - 1

        For i = 2 To 500
        t = sign * ((x - 1) ^ i / i)
        If Abs(t) >= 0.0000001 Then
        Sum = Sum + t
        sign = -sign
        Else
        GoTo 12
        End If
        Next

        Else
        Sum = 0
        For i = 1 To 600
        t = ((x - 1) / x) ^ i
        If Abs(t) < 10000000 Then
        Sum = Sum + (t / i)
        Else
        GoTo 12
        End If
        Next
        End If
```